# Add transparent text in Email field that show what this field mean in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-screen

in the layout file in android , i want to add button contains transparent text that indicated to the user what this field means and when begin to entire text the transparent text disappear as photo in the link
http://www.mediafire.com/view/t93aa1qs6zfqq3s/Capture.PNG

Comment: give more explanation and show your code.

Answer (score 2):

Just add in your EditText, That will give hint to user that what they should do with that `EditText`.

**Using XML**

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edt_email"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Your Email" // This attribute will guide to user
android:inputType="textEmailAddress" // This will launch keyboard which have special email symbols. />
```

**Using Java**

```
EditText edt_email= (EditText) findviewbyid (R.id.edt_email);
edt_email.setHint("Your Email");
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: where add this code : android:hint="Type your Email Address here"

Comment: in your EditText Field

Answer (score 1):

To do this via **XML** then use this:--

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="Enter your email address"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="kailash@mail.com"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_etLogin" />
```

if you want to do **programmatically** then:--

```
  EditText etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
  etEmail.setHint("Enter your email address");
```

Comment: you should use lower case in your view id

Answer (score 0):

Just give this in EditText in xml file

```
android:hint="Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in your edit-text

```
android:hint="Your Text";  // XML
```

or even you can set it run time by using following code

```
EditText text = new (EditText) findviewbyid (R.id.text1);
text1.setHint("Enter your message here");
```